# kubernetes - multiple pods with same app on the same node

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, kubernetes-pod

We are migrating our infrastructure to kubernetes. I am talking about a part of it, that contains of an api for let's say customers (we have this case for many other resources). Let's consider we have a billion customers, each with some data etc. and we decided they deserve a specialized api just for them, with its own db, server, domain, etc.

Kubernetes has the notion of nodes and pods. So we said "ok, we dedicate node X with all its resources to this particular api". And now the question:

Why would I used multiple pods each of them containing the same nginx + fpm and code, and limit it to a part of traffic and resources, and add an internal lb, autoscale, etc., instead of having a single pod, with all node resources?

Since each pod adds a bit of extra memory consumption this seems like a waste to me. The only upside being the fact that if something fails only part of it goes down (so maybe 2 pods would be optimal in this case?).

Obviously, would scale the nodes when needed.

Note: I'm not talking about a case where you have multiple pods with different stuff, I'm talking about that particular case.

Note 2: The db already is outside this node, on it's own pod.

Google fails me on this topic. I find hundreds of post with "how to configure things, but 0 with WHY?".

Answer (score 2):

> Why would I used multiple pods each of them containing the same nginx + fpm and code, and limit it to a part of traffic and resources, and add an internal lb, autoscale, etc., instead of having a single pod, with all node resources?

> Since each pod adds a bit of extra memory consumption this seems like a waste to me. The only upside being the fact that if something fails only part of it goes down (so maybe 2 pods would be optimal in this case?).

This comes down to the question, should I scale my app **vertically (larger instance)** or **horizontally (more instances)**.

First, try to avoid using only a *single instance* since you probably want more redundancy if you e.g. upgrade a Node. A single instance may be a good option if you are OK with some downtime sometimes.

### Scale app vertically

To scale an app vertically, by changing the instance to a bigger, is a viable alternative that sometimes is a good option. Especially when the app can not be scaled horizontally, e.g. an app that use *leader election* pattern - typically listen to a specific event and react. There is however a limit by how much you can scale an app vertically.

### Scale app horizontally

For a stateless app, it is usually **much easier** and cheaper to scale an app horizontally by adding more instances. You typically want more than one instance anyway, since you want to tolerate that a Node goes down for maintenance. This is also possible to do for a large scale app to very many instances - and the cost scales linearly. However, not every app can scale horizontally, e.g. a distributed database (replicated) can typically not scale well horizontally unless you shard the data. You can even use [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to automatically adjust the number of instances depending on how busy the app is.

### Trade offs

As described above, horizontal scaling is usually easier and preferred. But there are trade offs - you would probably not want to run thousands of instances when you have low traffic - an instance has some resource overhead costs, also in maintainability. For *availability* you should run at least 2 pods and make sure that they does not run on the same node, if you have a *regional* cluster, you want to make sure that they does not run on the same *Availability Zone* - for availability reasons. Consider 2-3 pods when your traffic is low, and use [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to automatically scale up to more instance when you need. In the end, this is a number game - resources cost money - but you want to provide a good service for your customers as well.

Comment: +1 for effort but doesn't really answer my question (or maybe I don't get the essence?). We obviously want horizontal scaling, with the possibility of vertical scaling, but don't get how using multiple pods on same node (instance) help with that. I can have 1 pod / node and still scale horizontally (by adding one more node, with one more pod on it), and can also scale vertically with no downtime with a rolling / rolling with additional batch deploy on a new instance type, that has also 1 pod / node. Note: I didn't say 1 pod in total, I said 1 pod per node. Can achieve 0 downtime in all cases.

Comment: "but don't get how using multiple pods on same node (instance) help with that". E.g. Two or Four Pods can handle more traffic than a single Pod - this is horizontal scaling. I would not recommend to run them on the same node - instead make sure that they are running on different nodes - this increases your availability - if a Node goes down.

Comment: Ok... I understand the confusion. My question was not why should I have more pods in general. My question was why should I have more pods on the same node, if I plan to dedicate that node to a single task. To add more pods on same node where nothing else "lives" is until the node is full, while can be considered horizontal scaling doesn't seem useful (why not let one pod run with all resources? the end result is the same). Adding 1 more node is horizontal scaling in this case. Also I'm specifying in question it is about nginx + fpm (so you already have thread and process control from fpm).

Comment: Actually you already said "I would not recommend to run them on the same node". My question was is it usefull to have 1 node, scaling to 10000 nodes (horizontal scaling), each with 1 pod? Vs. 1 node, scaling to 10000 nodes, each with 10 pods doing the same thing (also horizontal scaling), in the case of nginx + fpm (since you can use pods to manage various services, I think it may be useful to have more pods for ex. on a nodejs environment, but that's beside the point, that's why I mentioned what I'm planning to have on it).

Comment: I have updated my answer with the trade offs. "if I plan to dedicate that node to a single task" - try to avoid pinning workload to a specific node, at least use a group of nodes - for availability. Things are easier to manage if your workload can use any node - and use Node Autoscaler to automatically add nodes when you have many pods.